# One Slicer that filters multiple slicers/tables (Mac friendly solution)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have an excel file (teams scores) with 3 different worksheets (Performance, Mood, Client Surveys). Each worksheet contain a different table but all 3 tables have a common Column called "Team Name".

**Objective:** The objective is to have Main Slicer that will be able to filter all the tables (and connected pivots/charts/Slicers) by Team Name.

**What I did:** I've created a Data model containing all the 3 tables (and the related pivots/charts/Slicers within the data model). I have created a new table containing unique Team Names (with a connected pivot and slicer) and made a relationship between each table and the unique one.
Everything was working as intended. When I filtered Unique slicer it was automatically filtering all pivots/charts/Slicers in all worksheets.

**The Problem:** I have some users with Mac pc and Data Model does not work on their excel version.

**The Question:** Is there a way (normal excel or VBA) to reach the same result but Mac friendly?

Many thanks for your help.

Sheet1 (Performance)

| Performance | Team Name |
| --- | --- |
| Fast | Team 1 |
| Slow | Team 2 |
| Average | Team 3 |

Sheet2 (Mood)

| Mood | Team Name |
| --- | --- |
| Sad | Team 1 |
| Happy | Team 2 |
| Happy | Team 3 |

Sheet3 (Client Survey)

| Mood | Team Name |
| --- | --- |
| Good Job | Team 1 |
| Bad Job | Team 2 |
| Neutral | Team 3 |

Answer (score 0):

While I am not very familiar with using VBA on a Mac, I will tell you how I would solve this in a windows enviroment.

1. Create a slicer for the first table.
2. Add a formula with a subtotal *(max)* or something, to get the team name that is currently selected, displayed in the cell.
3. Create VBA code that sets the filter on the other two tables, using the cell with the formulas as the filter criteria.
4. Create an on change event to fire the code. This will depend on how the rest of your spreadsheet is set up as for what to trigger the macro.